# Switch conditional statement inside map function

Tags: javascript, react-native, switch-statement

I am mapping over array of objects in react-native:

```
const status_image = [
            {
                image: require("../../assets/claimsImages/Question.png")
            },
            {
                image: require("../../assets/claimsImages/Approved.png")
            },
            {
                image: require("../../assets/claimsImages/In Process.png")
            },
            {
                image: require("../../assets/claimsImages/Cancelled.png")
            }
        ]

        this.state = {
            newdata: [],
            images: status_image,

        }


render(){
        var img = this.state.images.map( val => val.image);

        const claimData = this.state.newdata.map((val, index) => {
            return (
                <View key={index} style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', margin: 15,}}>

                        <View style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1,borderBottomColor: '#A6ACAF' }}>
                            <Text>EW</Text>
                            {val.claim_approval_status.map((status, i) => (

                                    <View style={{marginVertical: 12}}>
                                        <Image
                                            style={styles.stretch}
                                            source={img[i]}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                            ))}
                        </View>
                        <View>
                        {val.claim_approval_status.map((status, i) => (

                            <View style={{marginTop: 36}}>
                                <Text>{status}</Text>
                            </View>
                        ))}
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
    });
        return (
            <View>
                {claimData}
            </View>
        )

    }
```

What I want to achieve is the images should be mapped on the basis of status value i.e. if my **val.claim_approval_status** equals 'question', then the image 'Question.png' should be rendered in front of that status. If the **val.claim_approval_status** equals 'approved', then image be 'Approved.png'.

All these status values are mapped all together in a table along with the images, just the images need to appear as per their status values.

I tried following switch case approach likewise, but got confused implementing.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.state.newdata.map((x, i) => {
                x.claim_approval_status.map((y, i) => {
                    let status = y;
                    console.log(status) //this gives four status values 
                                        'question, approved, inprocess, 
                                         cancelled'
                });

           });

    var status_values = this.state.images.map((val, i) =>
      {
       switch (i) {
        case 1:
          // something to append that image in status data mapping
          break;
        case 2:
           // something to append that image in status data mapping
          break;
        case 3:
           // something to append that image in status data mapping
          break;
      }
     }
      // ...
    );
}
```

How can I achieve the result? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of switch case, you can apply simplest approach, by assigning object key as the status code, something like below:

```
const status_image = 
    {
        question: require("../../assets/claimsImages/question.png"),
        approved: require("../../assets/claimsImages/approved.png"),
        inprocess: require("../../assets/claimsImages/inprocess.png"),
        cancelled: require("../../assets/claimsImages/cancelled.png")
    };
```

and once you have the response you can just use

```
<Image 
    style={styles.stretch}
    source={status_image[status]}
/>
```

Comment: You need to make sure that response from the api and key of your images should be same.

Comment: Yes it is same. Approved.png , In Process.png and from response : `"claim_approval_status": [
                "Approved",
                "In Process"
            ]`

Comment: As I can see from your comment it is not same, neither "Approved" is same as "approved" nor "In Process" is same as "inprocess"

Comment: In the question I wrote it down in small letters. The actual is one that I am mentioning above. Sorry for typo mistakes in question.

Comment: As I said, it must be same, just replace json object keys with the response you are getting.

Comment: If you are getting 'In Progress' in response than json key should be `'In Progress' : require("../../assets/claimsImages/inprocess.png")` and so on

Comment: Please help to look at the problem: `cannot read property 'Approved' of undefined`